# Bound for the genus of the incompressible surfaces that can be embedded in a closed compact orientable irreducible 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology, submanifold

Let $M$ be a closed compact orientable irreducible 3-manifold. I would like to know if there exists  a bound $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that every incompressible surface embedded in $M$ has genus lesser than $n$.

I think this bound exists for Seifert manifolds, since the incompressible surfaces are isotopic to the base space or to a torus. However, I don't know if it is true in general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Provability_Computability_and_Reflection/QA91RdBlMooC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=genus+of+incompressible+surface&pg=PA436&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true, no such bound exists in general.

For example, if $M$ is a closed 3-manifold that fibers over the circle with fiber a closed, oriented surface $S$ of genus $\ge 2$, and if the rank of $H_2(M;\mathbb R)$ is $\ge 2$, then according to the theory of the [Thurston norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thurston_norm) on $H_2(M;\mathbb R)$ there exist other fibrations of $M$ over the circle whose fibers have arbitrarily large genus.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.